# Prove $F \cap(G+H)=F \cap G+F \cap H$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove the following:

If $F,G,H$ are vector subspaces of a vector space $E$, then
$F \cap(G+H)=F \cap G+F \cap H$

I tried to do it with double inclusion but I do not know how to start it.

Comment: Can you describe the properties of a vector in $F\cap (G+H)$?

Comment: Why do you need to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you cannot prove it is that it is not true.

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, and take the following three subspaces:
$$\begin{align*}
F &= \{ (x,0)\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}\\
G &= \{ (0,y)\mid y\in \mathbb{R}\}\\
H &= \{ (a,a)\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}.
\end{align*}$$

Then $G+H=V$, so $F\cap(G+H) = F$. But $F\cap G=F\cap H = \{(0,0)\}$, so $(F\cap G)+(F\cap H) = \{(0,0)\} + \{(0,0)\} = \{(0,0)\}\neq F$.